# java jframe window not resizing

Tags: java, resize, jframe

When I run my program, the window is smaller than it should be looking at my design tab for creating a JFrame.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this?

It keeps cutting off the bottom of my program no matter what adjustments I make.

The code:

```
private void solveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        //recieving variable A
        String inputA = txtInputA.getText();
        double varA = Double.parseDouble(inputA);

        //recieving variable B
        String inputB = txtInputB.getText();
        double varB = Double.parseDouble(inputB);

        //recieving variable C
        String inputC = txtInputC.getText();
        double varC = Double.parseDouble(inputC);

        //pluging the variables into the quadratic formula (solving for x)
        double varX = Math.sqrt((varB * varB) - (4.0 * varA * varC));
        varX = (-varB + varX) / (2.0 * varA);
        double varX2 = Math.sqrt((varB * varB) - (4.0 * varA * varC));
        varX2 = (-varB - varX2) / (2.0 * varA); 

        //rounding results 
        varX = Math.round(varX * 100.0) / 100.0;
        varX2 = Math.round(varX2 * 100.0) / 100.0;

        //displaying results to user
        txtOutput.setText("X = " + varX + "            " + "X = " + varX2);
```

Comment: What are you designing it with?

Comment: Paste your code please.

Comment: `When I go to run my program, the window is smaller than it should be looking at my design tab for creating a JFrame.` How small is it from your expected dimension?

Comment: dimensions are 390,386

Comment: problem is solved. I moved on of my labels over a bit and now it runs at the correct dimensions. I don't know why this worked but it did. Thanks to all of you that gave some helpful advice.

Answer (score 1):

After adding your components to the frame, call `pack` on the frame, it will use the container's layout manager to calculate the preferred viewable size and pack the frame around it

Answer (score 0):

The maths calculations seems redundant here so i don't understand why you included it. But it could be possible one of your components have a set minimum or maximum size, which could be whats messing up the size. Edit your question with the sufficient code for people to get a better understanding of the problem and come to a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

`JFrame frameobject = new JFramee();
frameobject.setResizable(true);`

It will solve your re-sizing problem.

Comment: if your size is wrong, you can use `frameobject.setsize(x,y)` method.

Comment: Then how to calculate the amount of space you need? Setting the frame to been non-resizable won't magically make the window the right size. Using `setSize` is just a guessing game and different OS's effect the size of the frame decorations, further messing with the dimensions. Overall, both `setResizable` and `setSize` are the wrong things to do